# maxlength not working in textarea for ckeditor angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ckeditor, maxlength

I have created an application in angularjs with ckeditor plugin, I have created a directive for ckeditor, The application is working fine but the issue is that i need to set a max character length to be 50, so i put `maxlength="50"`, but its not working,

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpqc4xhy/)**

**html**

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h3>CKEditor 4.2:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="editor in ckEditors">
    <textarea data-ng-model="editor.value" maxlength="50" data-ck-editor></textarea>
    <br />
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addEditor()">New Editor</button>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);

            ck.on('pasteState', function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            });

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            };
        }
    };
}])

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.ckEditors = [{value: ''}];
}
```

Comment: use ng-maxlength instead of maxlength..

Comment: @Ved its not working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpqc4xhy/1/)

Comment: maxlength is working  fine for textarea but, when you add directive , It is not working..

Comment: @Ved yes...so is there any solution for this

Comment: I will try.. But actually I don't know how you are using Directive, so don't know what will be the optimum solution..

Comment: I think you should do this, using javascript. make a function to check the length of value inside textarea. call this function inside ng-change=""; in textArea

Comment: @Ved ng-change is working ....but how to prevent stop typing beyond 50

Answer (score 6):

You need to add an `id` to your `textarea`, like this:

```
<textarea data-ng-model="editor.value" maxlength="50" id="mytext" data-ck-editor></textarea>
```

You need to handle the key events for `CKEDITOR`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.mytext.on( 'key', function() {
        var str = CKEDITOR.instances.mytext.getData();
        if (str.length > 50) {
            CKEDITOR.instances.mytext.setData(str.substring(0, 50));
        }
    } );
};
```

This works, however, note, that the content contains html tags as well, you might want to keep them,

Comment: can you give me a jsfiddle

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpqc4xhy/. However, as I pointed out, my example does not handle the html inside the CKEDITOR. You need to parse it as well, since my code only checks the length and truncates it if too long.

Comment: actually i am looking for how to limit the html inside CKEDITOR

Comment: Did you check my code? It does just that. You need to handle <p> and other things though.

Comment: but i can type beyond 50 charcters, its not preventing that

Comment: hey cant we write that function within the directive

Comment: For some reason my changes were not saved. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpqc4xhy/5/. And if unsuccessful, then please add the code I have described in my answer. You should at least cooperate if we are helping you.

Comment: Good question. I have never used CKEDITOR, so I do not know. I have just solved your problem by adding the id and implementing the function. You can give it a better form, naturally. My code is only a proof-of-concept. You need an html parser to handle the tags, as <p> adds to the total length and you can restructure your code if you want to.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this same issue. I made this function which works with CKEditor to basically mimic the maxlength function.

```
window.onload = function() {            
    CKEDITOR.instances.mytext.on('key',function(event){
        var deleteKey = 46;
        var backspaceKey = 8;
        var keyCode = event.data.keyCode;
        if (keyCode === deleteKey || keyCode === backspaceKey)
            return true;
        else
        {
            var textLimit = 50;
            var str = CKEDITOR.instances.mytext.getData();
            if (str.length >= textLimit)
                return false;
        }
    });    
};
```

This function will check to make sure the input does not have more than the allowed characters.

If it does it will return false which simply does not allow any more inputs into the field.

If the user presses backspace or delete then it will return true which still allows the user to change their content if they reach the content limit.

Comment: You can use `var str = event.editor.getData();` in the `else` block to make this dynamic.

Additionally, this doesn't account for when a user has entered the maximum amount of text and then inserts a link.