# CK editor. Set maximum word count per page?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to set a maximum word count for a CK editor per page?

Or even better: per editor?

I can't find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think CKeditor performs this out of the box. Try reading here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27720326/42446

or..

https://divgo.wordpress.com/2013/01/04/ckeditor-maxlength-plugin/

Comment: Thank you for the links!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution inside the CKEditor doc; I've tested it with CKEditor 4.7.3. See url: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_configuration

1) create a copy of your config.js file (possibly in the same location although the example shows differently)

2) Add whatever settings you need e.g.:

Limit nb char: "config.wordcount = { maxCharCount: 255, showWordCount: true, showCharCount: true};"

Or

Limit nb words: "config.wordcount = { maxWordCount: 255, showWordCount: true, showCharCount: true};"

3) In the page that requires a specific config, add the following to the lines that call CKEditor for textarea replacement

ex: CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {customConfig: '/custom/ckeditor_config.js'});

4) and you're done :-) might require a ctrl refresh on your page to reload the new settings

Remember that you need extra plugins to make the word count work: htmlwriter, notification, undo, and wordcount. See ref doc: https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wordcount

Answer (score 1):

In CKEditor 4 you can edit your `config.js` to have limits on chars and words. You need to include the Wordcount plugin.

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

        // Include 'wordcount' plugin
        config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount'; 

           config.wordcount = {

                    // Whether or not you want to show the Paragraphs Count
                    showParagraphs: false,

                    // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
                    showWordCount: true,

                    // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
                    showCharCount: true,

                    // Whether or not you want to count Spaces as Chars
                    countSpacesAsChars: false,

                    // Whether or not to include Html chars in the Char Count
                    countHTML: false,

                    // Whether or not to include Line Breaks in the Char Count
                    countLineBreaks: false,

                    // Maximum allowed Word Count, -1 is default for unlimited
                    // NOTE - This is where you configure Max Word Count
                    maxWordCount: -1,

                    // Maximum allowed Char Count, -1 is default for unlimited
                    maxCharCount: 250,

                    // Maximum allowed Paragraphs Count, -1 is default for unlimited
                    maxParagraphs: 1,

                    // How long to show the 'paste' warning, 0 is default for not auto-closing the notification
                    pasteWarningDuration: 0,


                    // Add filter to add or remove element before counting (see CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter), Default value : null (no filter)
                    filter: new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter({
                        elements: {
                            div: function( element ) {
                                if(element.attributes.class == 'mediaembed') {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                };

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the CK editor,paste it in Res folder.
Download wordcount plugin and paste it in CKEditor's Plugin folder.

Then in config.cs (present inside CKEditor folder), Paste this :

```
        config.extraPlugins = 'wordcount';
        config.wordcount = {

            // Whether or not you want to show the Word Count
            showWordCount: true,

            // Whether or not you want to show the Char Count
            showCharCount: false,

            // Maximum allowed Word Count
            maxWordCount: -1,

            // Maximum allowed Char Count
            maxCharCount: 10
};
```

Then in HTML use this :

```
/*        If instance is already present then destory it 
 * 
 */
          var currentEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.answerCKEditor;
            if (currentEditor) {
                currentEditor.destroy(true); 
            }   
          CKEDITOR.replace('answerCKEditor',{wordcount: {
                showParagraphs: false,
                showWordCount: true,
                showCharCount: true,
                countSpacesAsChars: false,
                countHTML: false,
                maxWordCount: -1,
                maxCharCount: 40}
            });

      });
```

This will replace the normal TextArea:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Answer</label>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" id="answerCKEditor" rows="6" cols="50" th:text="${faqDetail.answer}"></textarea>
</div>
```