# Limit CKEditor to one word page

Tags: ms-word, ckeditor

Is there a way we can actually limit what you can type and insert (words, images, etc) into a ckeditor page equal to what we can fit into one MS word page?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `maxLength` attribute should help answer your question. Just figure out how many characters a typical MS Word document can hold in a single page and add the `maxLength` attribute to your textarea for CKEditor. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719498/maxlength-not-working-in-textarea-for-ckeditor-angularjs-directive) question on SO and see [this](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.textInput-property-maxLength) page in the CKEditor documentation.